# Why can I not place a tile that scores more than 10 points in Kodama: Tree Spirits

Tags: untagged

The the game [Kodama: The Tree Spirits](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/181810/kodama-tree-spirits), there is a limit on scoring more than 10 points in a single move.

Is there a reason for this given? If so it's not in the rules book so the 2004 edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess it is to keep the tree growing in many directions and not just along a single path. Since scoring is based on how many icons from the card you played are on other cards in a path to the bottom it would make the most sense to never branch off and victory comes down to who gets the best card draws. With this rule in place there is more strategy to where a card is placed not only to maximize your points but to minimize other players points.

[Rules](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/kodama-the-tree-spirits/game-rules.php)

> After placing a branch card, look at the icons on that card. You score 1 point for each instance of those icons in that contiguous line of cards. You do not score points for other instances of that icon if they are not part of this contiguous line of cards.

> You only score points based on the icons on the branch card you added this turn. Those icons must be part of a contiguous line of cards with the card you just added. Any other icons elsewhere on the tree do not score points.

> The contiguous line of cards extends from the card you just added, continuing down toward the trunk or until the shared icons do not appear on a card.

Comment: A lot of the decree and kodama cards also push you to make a more branchy tree, rather than a long branch. I wonder if they discovered that wasn't enough?

Comment: I am not sure of what those cards do exactly but it could very well be that even with those decree cards it is still better point wise to keep a single branch going. I am guessing that it gets to the point fairly quickly where even the extra points from a decree card are not as much as playing a card and getting 30 or 40 points from that play alone.

Comment: Points would grow like fibonacci or triangle numbers...which I think [DOES grow exponential.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981007/is-the-fibonacci-sequence-exponential) But only if you get the right cards.